# How to programmatically recreate Microsoft Excel's cell dimensions autofit() function for merged cells?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

Currently I am creating a script capable of transferring large documents from word into excel using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop` namespace. I've managed to put enough code together to get everything operating correctly but I ran into a small issue. I've learnt Microsoft Excel doesn't offer autofitting function for merged cells. As my program relies on unmerging certain rows to allow for viewable data tables unless there is some way to split cells, which I've never heard of, I'd need to keep my cells merged. Currently I've been attempting to recreate something close to the AutoFit() function but without knowing Microsoft's process I've been unable to recreate the function. Currently I've been doing a word count and adjusting the row height depending on the amount of words transferred from a certain paragraph, I've been considering changing this to each individual character but this would multiply my process time tenfold.

Current AutoFit() recreation(where count is number of words in current paragraph):

```cs
wks.Cells[r, c].RowHeight = (count / 15) * 16;
```

Extremely slower AutoFit() recreation concept(where count is number of characters and x is average number of characters in a line):

```cs
wks.Cells[r, c].RowHeight = (count / x) * 16;
```

Can attach more code if it would make any responses more accurate, but I expect it would just cause distraction.

I guess what my question would be is there a way to automatically adjust row height in a fashion similar to Microsoft Excel's Autofit function? If anyone has any recommendations or insight into Microsoft's process for autofitting cells I'd love to receive any feedback.

Update 2020-11-04: Still have been unable to find any explanation for the function, nor found a method to check for line length in pixels that could then be applied to row height. I'm still sure there has to be a way though as Excel itself does it programmatically.

Comment: So your cells are wrapping? measuring fonts by hand is hard. IMHO set the row height to some maximum `N*font height`, auto-fit columns, then auto-fit rows. Excel should be able to work out something usable from that.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought I'd try. But it's just Excel won't allow me to use auto-fit with merged cells right? Which is where the issue is mostly found as I'm merging many cells that include text.

Comment: Copy the value to `Hidden!A1` and auto fit that?